# jQuery traverse parent n levels, find sibling, then find class within that sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two divs next to each other with several levels of children in each. Whenever a child in the second set of divs is clicked, I need to find the most previous instance of a class and change it. (Hint, that instance is as follows in my high level picture):

```
<div class="junk">
    <div>
        <div class="bCommonS bsC"></div>
        <div class="bCommonS bsN"></div>
        <div class="bCommonS bsS">I access stuff here</div>
    </div>
<div>

<div>
    <ul>
        ...
        <li>...</li>
        <li>
            <div>
                <div></div>
                <div data-category="junk">When this is clicked</div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>...</li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

Right now, I'm just trying to perform a basic css change to show that I've successfully accessed the div.

```
$(this).parent().eq(4).prev().find(".bsS").css("background-color", "purple");
```

This is a line of crappy code that doesn't work. I've tried many others (not using the `.eq()`). I've tried `parent(".parentClass").prev(".prevClassToParent").find(".bsS")..` and I've tried many other renditions, but *can't seem to figure how I can access the previous most occurrence of a class*.

Thanks for any help one may provide!

*** *FIX* *****

```
var cat = $(this).data("category");
var catBar = $("."+cat).find(".bCommonS");
var updateBarS = catBar.filter(".bsS").css("background-color", "purple");
```

Comment: Sorry. I'm confused. Where is, for instance, elements with class "bsS" in the example above? I think we need the complete code to better understand your point. You might consider using jsfiddle to support the main idea with further details. I actually just didn't get which div is each div you've mentioned.

Comment: I updated the original question to list where `.bsS` is, which is above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is not direct answer to your question, here it goes

Consider changing your layout and adding either some extra classes or some extra `data-` attributes to your layout, take a look at example:

```
<div class='allstuff'>
    <div>
        <div class='stuff id1'></div>
        <div class='stuff id2'></div>
        <div class='stuff id3'>I access stuff here</div>
    </div>
<div>

<div>
    <ul>
        ...
        <li class='link' data-stuff='id1'>...</li>
        <li class='link' data-stuff='id2'>
            <div>
                <div></div>
                <div>When this is clicked</div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class='link' data-stuff='id3'>...</li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

This whay your selector will be quite simple:

```
    var allstuff = $('.allstuff').find('.stuff')
    $('link').on('click', function(e) {
        var id = $(this).closest('link').data('stuff')
        var stuff= allstuff.filter('.'+id).css("background-color", "purple");
    })
```

Comment: Thanks a a lot! I never knew about `data-` attributes. This helped me precisely. I've updated my original question with how I implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your structure correctly you could do something as simple as this:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/47x7j/)**

```
$('.click').click(function () {
    $('.bsS').parent().children(':last-child').css("background-color", "purple");
});
```

API Docs:
[.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)
[.children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/)
[:last-child](https://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This seems to also access the `.bsS` after my clicked button, so the background changes in two places.

Comment: @Kenny can you show us what your HTML really looks like? I only see 1 `.bsS` in the question.